# Importing Excel to DataGrid using ClosedXML and OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, datatable, closedxml

I want to load an Excel-file into my DataGrid, using ClosedXML.

I have this method:

```
public static DataTable ImportExceltoDataTable(string filePath, string sheetName) {

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new(filePath)) {

        IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
        DataTable dt = new();

        bool firstRow = true;
        foreach (IXLRow row in ws.Rows()) {

            if (firstRow) {
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells()) {
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.CachedValue.ToString());
                }
                
                firstRow = false;

            } else {
      
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;
          
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(row.FirstCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber, row.LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber)) {
                
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i} = cell.CachedValue.ToString();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
 
        return dt;
    }
}
```

And on a click-event, I am trying to pick my file using `OpenFileDialog`, see below:

```
OpenFileDialog of = new();
of.Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx;";
of.Title = "Import Excel file.";

if (of.ShowDialog()==true) {

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = ImportExceltoDataTable("...", "...").DefaultView;
}
```

But I do not know how to notify the `DataTable` that I've chosen a file in my `OpenFileDialog`.
At the first line in the `DataTable` method, I get the following exception error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Empty extension is not supported'

Which makes sense... How can I tell it what file I've picked?

Comment: After the user picks the file, the picked file’s path and name would be in the dialogs `FileName` property. Example… `of.FileName` will contain the full path and file name of the file the user selected. This will give you the first parameter to the `ImportExceltoDataTable`, however, the `OpenFileDialog` is NOT going to “open” the file and let the user “select” a worksheet. So it is unclear how you plan to get the second `sheetName` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @JohnG - do I need to specify a sheet? I tried removing it, and added `of.FileName`, but then received a new exception at the 2nd foreach loop: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. 

If I put a break-point, I see that the foreach loop goes through each cell and gets its value.
When the exception happens, the `row` of the loop contains `{ALL!A7213:XFD7213}`. ALL being the name of my sheet.

Comment: Pass the selected file path and the name of the method and make sure that your implementation actually works: `dataGrid.ItemsSource = ImportExceltoDataTable(of.FileName, "Sheet1").DefaultView;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to re-think your approach to reading the excel file. One possible issue is the `if (firstRow) { …` … statement, which is odd and makes a dangerous assumption. The code “assumes” that each column of data “has” a header cell. In other words, the number of columns added to the `DataTable` will be determined by the number of cells found (with some text in the cell) on the “FIRST” row. What if a column of data does NOT have a header cell?

Therefore, if there are any rows that have data to the right of the first row’s cells with headers, then the `DataTable` will not have the correct number of columns… and, when the code gets to these cells in the `else` portion below… the code will most likely crash when `i` goes beyond `dt`’s column count.

The code needs to guarantee that `dt` has the correct number of columns to avoid the problem described above. One way to help is to find the two cells that define the “top-left” cell where the data begins (as it may not necessarily always be the first cell in the worksheet) and “bottom-right” cell where the “last” cell with data is located.

Once we have these two cells (top-left and bottom-right)… then, we can determine how many columns are needed in the `DataTable`… and… we can almost guarantee that all the data in the worksheet will fit in the `DataTable`.

Below is one possible solution using the ideas described above. Note, the code below does not use a particular worksheet name and simply uses the first worksheet in the given workbook.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
  of.Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx;";
  of.Title = "Import Excel file.";
  if (of.ShowDialog() == true) {
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = ImportExceltoDataTable(of.FileName).DefaultView;
  }
}

public static DataTable ImportExceltoDataTable(string filePath) {
  using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(filePath)) {
    IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
    int tl_Row = ws.FirstCellUsed().Address.RowNumber;
    int tl_Col = ws.FirstCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber;
    int br_Row = ws.LastCellUsed().Address.RowNumber;
    int br_Col = ws.LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    // add dt columns using the first row of data
    for (int i = tl_Col; i <= br_Col; i++) {
      dt.Columns.Add(ws.Cell(tl_Row, i).CachedValue.ToString());
    }
    IXLRow currentRow;
    // add data from the worksheet to dt - we already used the first row of data for the columns
    for (int dtRow = 0; dtRow < br_Row - tl_Row; dtRow++) {
      currentRow = ws.Row(tl_Row + dtRow + 1);
      dt.Rows.Add();
      for (int dtCol = 0; dtCol < br_Col - tl_Col + 1; dtCol++) {
        dt.Rows[dtRow][dtCol] = currentRow.Cell(tl_Col + dtCol).CachedValue; 
      }
    }
    return dt;
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for taking the time to pen that out for me.
Works like a charm - very grateful! Now onto the next hurdle....